# add member routes to resources as concerns

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I would like to extract 'like', 'unlike' routes into a concern then apply it to different resources.

```
concern :likeable do
  member do
    post :like
    post :unlike
  end
end

resources users, concerns: :likeable
resources equipment, concerns: :likeable
```

Is anything similar possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working despite the fact that it is not mentioned in the rails guides.

Comment: The [routing section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#routing-concerns) explains concerns let you `declare common routes`. So everything should work inside a concern. Plus you posted a question without even trying it yourself, only to give an answer "it works" 5 minutes after.

Comment: At the time of asking it wasn't documented. I needed to try because it seems logical to have support for it.